# Heatmap Layer not displaying in Google Maps API (@react-google-maps/api)

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps, react-google-maps-api

I'm trying to get a Heatmap layer to show within google maps inside my React application. When I `npm start` I get the following application:

[image: Google Maps View]

However, there is no visible Heatmap layer even though I provided the HeatmapLayer as a child component to the GoogleMap comp and passed in hardcoded data in the format as described by the documentation that can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api

```
import env from "react-dotenv";
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript, HeatmapLayer } from '@react-google-maps/api'

const containerStyle = {
  width: '400px',
  height: '400px'
};

const center = {
  lat: 37.765153,
  lng: -122.418618
};

function App() {

  const {isLoaded} = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: env.REACT_APP_MAPS_API_KEY,
    libraries: ["visualization"],
  })
  
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null)
  
  const onLoad = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
    const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds(center);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    setMap(map)
  }, [])

  const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
    setMap(null)
  }, [])

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading</div>
  }

  const heatmapData = 
    [
      new window.google.maps.LatLng(37.765153, -122.418618),
      new window.google.maps.LatLng(37.765136, -122.419112),
      new window.google.maps.LatLng(37.765129, -122.419378),
      new window.google.maps.LatLng(37.765119, -122.419481),
      new window.google.maps.LatLng(37.7651, -122.419852),
    ]

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
      center={center}
      zoom={10}
      onLoad={onLoad}
      onUnmount={onUnmount}
    >
      <HeatmapLayer data={heatmapData} />
    </GoogleMap>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I just started working with this API and do not fully understand how it works. An explanation of the onLoad/onUnmount and `map` object would be very much appreciated alongside a solution.

Thanks all!

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this?

Comment: I did however I trashed this project and don't believe I have the solution on hand anymore... @Richardsondx

Answer (score 2):

if you are using the latest versions of React then try  instead of

```
import {HeatmapLayerF, MarkerF} from '@react-google-maps/api';
```

Comment: I have a problem with HeatmapLayerF, when I build the app throw the next error: ` Attempted import error: 'HeatmapLayerF' is not exported from '@react-google-maps/api' (imported as 'HeatmapLayerF').`